# Can I use linear regression to find the strongest predictor?

Tags: regression, predictor

I have 3 different techniques for measuring an effect, which is my independent variable. The value produced by each technique is different. Thus I want to find out which one of these 3 techniques is the strongest predictor of my dependent variable.

Can I use multiple linear regression to find this out? If so, what does the $R^2$ value in this case mean?

As I understand, if I use multiple linear regression in the form
**Predictor = Constant + Beta1*Technique1 Beta2*Technique2+Beta3*Technique3 + error**
the $R^2$ value indicates the variance explained by all the three variables. However, I have only one variable, which in this case has been measured in 3 different ways.

Comment: What do you mean by stronger predictor? Can you give an example of the 3 techniques? If it's about which one seems to have the most important effect, you could just compare betas of your linear regression after standardizing your variables.

Comment: +1 and welcome to Cross Validated! Is your goal to assess which model gets the tightest fit to your data? What kind of independent variable do you have? There are a bunch of ways to make this assessment, depending on what your independent variable is and what you value in a prediction (such as missing high being much worse than missing low).

Comment: There will always be an apparently strongest predictor.   The question is do the data have enough information to be confident in the "winner".  A method that fully exposes the difficulty of the task, especially when there are collinearities among $X$s, is to bootstrap th ranks of predictor importance (partial $R^2$ or any other measure you choose).  An example is given here: https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/validate.html#sec-val-bootrank

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by stronger predictor? Can you give an example of the 3 techniques? If it's about which one seems to have the most important effect, you could just compare betas of your linear regression after standardizing your variables.

Comment: *Pace* the flag, this post *does* constitute an answer: it proposes using standardized parameter estimates. (Whether that's good or appropriate is another matter, but that's also indicated in the first line of this answer.)

Comment: @whuber I see this more as a comment than an answer, since it starts asking for clarification, but maybe you are right.

Comment: @utobi Yes, it's on the borderline and would benefit from some elaboration.  However, I think we should favor keeping answers up in such cases rather than deleting them.